# SpeechSynthesizer and SSML

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, ssml, azure-speech, speechsynthesizer

I have been trying to work with the prosody pitch attribute but doesn't seem straightforward or seem to work.  I want to create a simple "do re mi" following the g-major scale.  The results do not turn out as expected using the various Hz values.  Sometimes it seems to do what it wants regardless of what I put.  Example:

```
        <prosody pitch="0Hz">A</prosody><break time="100ms" />
        <prosody pitch="+2st">E</prosody><break time="100ms" />
        <prosody pitch="+4st">I</prosody><break time="100ms" />
        <prosody pitch="+6st">O</prosody><break time="100ms" />
        <prosody pitch="+8st">U</prosody><break time="100ms" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all the alternatives, Amazon, Google, etc, they all say that Neural voices do not fully support pitch.  I suspect the same with the SpeechSynthesizer, which explains the inconsistent results.  Microsoft, please update your documentation accordingly.

The following MS documentation is not completely true:

Important
Pitch contour changes are now supported with neural voices.